# Build an empty Unity project to build an apk file failed

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am trying to build an empty Unity project through the platform Android inside Unity. I want to build the project to export an apk file but it failed.

Bellow you can find the error messages that I obtained.

`Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/AsyncPluginsFromLinker: Burst internal compiler error: Burst.Compiler.IL.Aot.AotLinkerException: Non 0 exit code | The native link step failed. Check previous exception in the log - linker command line : "Unity/Hub/Editor/2022.3.4f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/NDK/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang '@/tmp/tmp13b2a5.tmp'" UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&) (at /home/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Modules/IMGUI/GUIUtility.cs:190)`

`Building Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/AsyncPluginsFromLinker failed with output: UnityEditor.Build.BuildFailedException: Burst compiler (1.8.7) failed running`

`Build completed with a result of 'Failed' in 20 seconds (20414 ms)`

The Unity released installed is the "2022.3.4f1 LTS" and in "Edit -> Project Settings -> Player" I filled the package name.

**EDIT:**
**I changed the version of the Editor to "2023.1.3f1" (on Kali Linux) and I obtained the above error messages:**

```
Building Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/x6ly2/1kgcyu7aglsq.o failed with output:
```

clang: error: no input files

#0 GetStacktrace(int)
#1 DebugStringToFile(DebugStringToFileData const&)
#2 DebugLogHandler_CUSTOM_Internal_Log_Injected(LogType, LogOption, ScriptingBackendNativeStringPtrOpaque*, void*)
#3  (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log_Injected (UnityEngine.LogType,UnityEngine.LogOption,string,intptr)
#4  (Mono JIT Code) [BeeBuildPostprocessor.cs:612] UnityEditor.Modules.BeeBuildPostprocessor:ReportBuildResults ()
#5  (Mono JIT Code) [BeeBuildPostprocessor.cs:771] UnityEditor.Modules.BeeBuildPostprocessor:PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs)
#6  (Mono JIT Code) [BeeBuildPostprocessor.cs:37] UnityEditor.Modules.BeeBuildPostprocessor:PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs,UnityEditor.BuildProperties&)
#7  (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor:PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs,UnityEditor.BuildProperties&)
#8  (Mono JIT Code) [PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:273] UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer:Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup,UnityEditor.BuildTarget,int,string,string,string,UnityEditor.BuildOptions,UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry,UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport)
#9  (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper runtime-invoke) :runtime_invoke_void_int_int_int_object_object_object_int_object_object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr)
#10 mono_get_runtime_build_info
#11 mono_runtime_invoke
#12 mono_runtime_invoke
#13 scripting_method_invoke(ScriptingMethodPtr, ScriptingObjectPtr, ScriptingArguments&, ScriptingExceptionPtr*, bool)
#14 ScriptingInvocation::Invoke(ScriptingExceptionPtr*, bool)
#15 Scripting::UnityEditor::PostprocessBuildPlayerProxy::Postprocess(int, int, int, core::basic_string<char, core::StringStorageDefault > const&, core::basic_string<char, core::StringStorageDefault > const&, core::basic_string<char, core::StringStorageDefault > const&, int, ScriptingObjectPtr, ScriptingObjectPtr, ScriptingExceptionPtr*)
#16 DoBuildPlayer(BuildPlayerSetup const&, dynamic_array<EditorSceneBackup, 0ul>&, core::basic_string<char, core::StringStorageDefault >, dynamic_array<core::basic_string<char, core::StringStorageDefault >, 0ul> const&, bool, BuildReporting::BuildReport&, BuildReporting::BuiltAssetBundleInfo*, core::basic_string<char, core::StringStorageDefault > const&)
#17 BuildPlayerStep(BuildPlayerSetup const&, BuildReporting::BuildReport&)
#18 BuildPlayer(BuildPlayerSetup const&, BuildReporting::BuildReport&)
#19 BuildPipeline_CUSTOM_BuildPlayerInternalNoCheck(ScriptingBackendNativeArrayPtrOpaque*, ScriptingBackendNativeStringPtrOpaque*, ScriptingBackendNativeStringPtrOpaque*, BuildTargetPlatformGroup, BuildTargetPlatform, int, BuildPlayerOptions, ScriptingBackendNativeArrayPtrOpaque*, unsigned char)
#20  (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEditor.BuildPipeline:BuildPlayerInternalNoCheck (string[],string,string,UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup,UnityEditor.BuildTarget,int,UnityEditor.BuildOptions,string[],bool)
#21  (Mono JIT Code) [BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:168] UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow/DefaultBuildMethods:BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions)
#22  (Mono JIT Code) [BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:96] UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:CallBuildMethods (bool,UnityEditor.BuildOptions)
#23  (Mono JIT Code) [BuildPlayerWindow.cs:1099] UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:GUIBuildButtons (UnityEditor.Modules.IBuildWindowExtension,bool,bool,bool,UnityEditor.Build.BuildPlatform,UnityEditor.Modules.IBuildPostprocessor)
#24  (Mono JIT Code) [BuildPlayerWindow.cs:529] UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:OnGUI ()
#25  (Mono JIT Code) [HostView.cs:510] UnityEditor.HostView:InvokeOnGUI (UnityEngine.Rect)
#26  (Mono JIT Code) [DockArea.cs:395] UnityEditor.DockArea:DrawView (UnityEngine.Rect)
#27  (Mono JIT Code) [IMGUIContainer.cs:705] UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:HandleIMGUIEvent (UnityEngine.Event,UnityEngine.Matrix4x4,UnityEngine.Rect,System.Action,bool)
#28  (Mono JIT Code) [IMGUIContainer.cs:675] UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:HandleIMGUIEvent (UnityEngine.Event,System.Action,bool)
#29  (Mono JIT Code) [IMGUIContainer.cs:668] UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:HandleIMGUIEvent (UnityEngine.Event,bool)
#30  (Mono JIT Code) [IMGUIContainer.cs:617] UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:SendEventToIMGUI (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,bool,bool)
#31  (Mono JIT Code) [EventDispatchUtilities.cs:410] UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatchUtilities:DispatchToCapturingElement (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.UIElements.BaseVisualElementPanel,int,UnityEngine.Vector2)
#32  (Mono JIT Code) [EventDispatchUtilities.cs:359] UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatchUtilities:DispatchToCapturingElementOrElementUnderPointer (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.UIElements.BaseVisualElementPanel,int,UnityEngine.Vector2)
#33  (Mono JIT Code) [EventDispatcher.cs:292] UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher:ProcessEventQueue ()
#34  (Mono JIT Code) [EventDispatcher.cs:257] UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher:OpenGate ()
#35  (Mono JIT Code) [EventDispatcher.cs:201] UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher:Dispatch (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.UIElements.BaseVisualElementPanel,UnityEngine.UIElements.DispatchMode)
#36  (Mono JIT Code) [Panel.cs:480] UnityEngine.UIElements.BaseVisualElementPanel:SendEvent (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.UIElements.DispatchMode)
#37  (Mono JIT Code) [UIElementsUtility.cs:205] UnityEngine.UIElements.UIElementsUtility:UnityEngine.UIElements.IUIElementsUtility.ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
#38  (Mono JIT Code) [UIElementsUtility.cs:28] UnityEngine.UIElements.UIEventRegistration/<>c:<.cctor>b__1_2 (int,intptr)

```
Build completed with a result of 'Failed' in 51 seconds (50898 ms)
```

3 errors
#0 GetStacktrace(int)
#1 DebugStringToFile(DebugStringToFileData const&)
#2 DebugLogHandler_CUSTOM_Internal_Log_Injected(LogType, LogOption, ScriptingBackendNativeStringPtrOpaque*, void*)
#3  (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log_Injected (UnityEngine.LogType,UnityEngine.LogOption,string,intptr)
#4  (Mono JIT Code) [BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:96] UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:CallBuildMethods (bool,UnityEditor.BuildOptions)
#5  (Mono JIT Code) [BuildPlayerWindow.cs:1099] UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:GUIBuildButtons (UnityEditor.Modules.IBuildWindowExtension,bool,bool,bool,UnityEditor.Build.BuildPlatform,UnityEditor.Modules.IBuildPostprocessor)
#6  (Mono JIT Code) [BuildPlayerWindow.cs:529] UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:OnGUI ()
#7  (Mono JIT Code) [HostView.cs:510] UnityEditor.HostView:InvokeOnGUI (UnityEngine.Rect)
#8  (Mono JIT Code) [DockArea.cs:395] UnityEditor.DockArea:DrawView (UnityEngine.Rect)
#9  (Mono JIT Code) [IMGUIContainer.cs:705] UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:HandleIMGUIEvent (UnityEngine.Event,UnityEngine.Matrix4x4,UnityEngine.Rect,System.Action,bool)
#10  (Mono JIT Code) [IMGUIContainer.cs:675] UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:HandleIMGUIEvent (UnityEngine.Event,System.Action,bool)
#11  (Mono JIT Code) [IMGUIContainer.cs:668] UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:HandleIMGUIEvent (UnityEngine.Event,bool)
#12  (Mono JIT Code) [IMGUIContainer.cs:617] UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:SendEventToIMGUI (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,bool,bool)
#13  (Mono JIT Code) [EventDispatchUtilities.cs:410] UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatchUtilities:DispatchToCapturingElement (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.UIElements.BaseVisualElementPanel,int,UnityEngine.Vector2)
#14  (Mono JIT Code) [EventDispatchUtilities.cs:359] UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatchUtilities:DispatchToCapturingElementOrElementUnderPointer (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.UIElements.BaseVisualElementPanel,int,UnityEngine.Vector2)
#15  (Mono JIT Code) [EventDispatcher.cs:292] UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher:ProcessEventQueue ()
#16  (Mono JIT Code) [EventDispatcher.cs:257] UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher:OpenGate ()
#17  (Mono JIT Code) [EventDispatcher.cs:201] UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher:Dispatch (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.UIElements.BaseVisualElementPanel,UnityEngine.UIElements.DispatchMode)
#18  (Mono JIT Code) [Panel.cs:480] UnityEngine.UIElements.BaseVisualElementPanel:SendEvent (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.UIElements.DispatchMode)
#19  (Mono JIT Code) [UIElementsUtility.cs:205] UnityEngine.UIElements.UIElementsUtility:UnityEngine.UIElements.IUIElementsUtility.ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
#20  (Mono JIT Code) [UIElementsUtility.cs:28] UnityEngine.UIElements.UIEventRegistration/<>c:<.cctor>b__1_2 (int,intptr)

I hoop someone will help me.

Thank you

Comment: Build an apk file

Comment: You may need to look in the editor.log file for a more complete error message.

Comment: The post has been edited.